# CSV upload and change to php array for insert to db

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv

So I am wanting to allow users to:

```
1. Upload a .csv file (mystudents.csv)
2. Import the rows in the .csv
3. Create a PHP array for all this
4. Insert this information into a database
```

I have the following code to upload the file and create the array.

```
public function studentImport()
{
    ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', TRUE);

    $config['upload_path'] = './static/files/importFiles';
    $config['allowed_types'] = '*';
    $config['max_size'] = '800';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        var_dump($this->upload->display_errors());
    }
    else
    {
        $data = $this->upload->data();

        $file_path = './static/files/importFiles/'.$data['file_name'];

        $rows = array_map('str_getcsv', file($file_path));
        if($rows){
            $header = array_shift($rows);
            $csv = array();
            foreach($rows as $row) {
                $csv[] = array_combine($header, $row);
            }

            var_dump($csv);
        }
    }
}
```

The file gets uploaded just fine, but the errors happens with the line: `$rows = array_map('str_getcsv', file($file_path));`

And that error is:

```
array_map() [function.array-map]: The first argument, 'str_getcsv', should be either NULL or a valid callback
```

What do I need to do to make this work out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like the function `str_getcsv` is not available

Test it with

```
if (function_exists('str_getcsv')) {
  print "str_getcsv defined\n";
} else {
  print "str_getcsv not defined\n";
}
```

if function exists try

```
$csv= file_get_contents($file_path);
$array = str_getcsv($csv);
print json_encode($array);
```

or

```
$csv= file_get_contents($file_path);
$array = array_map('str_getcsv', explode("\n", $csv));
print json_encode($array);
```